# Export SQL DataBase to WinForm DataSet and then to MDB Database using DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, oledb

My application is a winform app that relies on a database. At startup of the application it connects to an SQL Database on the server and put this information in a DataSet/DataTable.

If for some reason the database on the server is not accessible, the application has a built in failover and it will get its information from the local database.

If, in a normal scenario, I start the tool it will read from the sql database and if it has been updated on the server (a seperate snippet checks this), it should make sure the local database is up to date and this is where the problem starts.. (see below)

*This part works fine and is added as context - this is where we connect to the SQL Database*

```
    public static DataSet dtsTableContents;
    public static DataTable CreateDatabaseSQLConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            string strSqlConnectionString = "Data Source=MyLocation;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;User=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;";
            SqlCommand scoCommand = new SqlCommand();
            scoCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection(strSqlConnectionString);
            scoCommand.Connection.Open();
            string strQueryToTable = "SELECT * FROM " + strTableName;
            dtsTableContents = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand scmTableInformation = new SqlCommand(strQueryToTable, scnConnectionToDatabase);
            SqlDataAdapter sdaTableInformation = new SqlDataAdapter(scmTableInformation);
            scnConnectionToDatabase.Open();
            sdaTableInformation.Fill(dtsTableContents, strTableName);
            DataTable dttTableInformation = dtsTableContents.Tables[strTableName];
            scnConnectionToDatabase.Close();
            return dttTableInformation;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This snippet is part of the failover method that reads from my local database...

*This part works fine and is added as context - this is where we connect to the MDB Database*

```
public static DataTable CreateDatabaseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=MyLocation;Persist Security Info=True;JET OLEDB:Database Password=MyPassword;"
            odcConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            odcConnection.Open();
            string strQueryToTable = "SELECT * FROM " + strTableName;
            DataSet dtsTableContents = new DataSet();
            OleDbCommand ocmTableInformation = new OleDbCommand(strQueryToTable, ocnConnectionToDatabase);
            OleDbDataAdapter odaTableInformation = new OleDbDataAdapter(ocmTableInformation);
            ocnConnectionToDatabase.Open();
            odaTableInformation.Fill(dtsTableContents, strTableName);
            DataTable dttTableInformation = dtsTableContents.Tables[strTableName];
            ocnConnectionToDatabase.Close();
            return dttTableInformation;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

From my CreateDatabaseSQLConnection() I have a DataSet. This DataSet is verified to contain all the information from the server database. Now I have been googling around and found myself trying to use this code to update the local database based on this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(v=vs.71).aspx

```
public static void UpdateLocalDatabase(string strTableName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (CreateDatabaseConnection() != null)
            {
                string strQueryToTable = "SELECT * FROM " + strTableName;
                OleDbDataAdapter odaTableInformation = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                odaTableInformation.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(strQueryToTable, odcConnection);
                OleDbCommandBuilder ocbCommand = new OleDbCommandBuilder(odaTableInformation);
                odcConnection.Open();
                odaTableInformation.Update(dtsTableContents, strTableName);
                odcConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

This snippet runs error-free but it does not seem to change anything. Also the time it takes to run this step takes like milliseconds and I would think this to take longer.

I am using the DataSet I obtained from my SQL Connection, this DataSet I am trying to write to my local database.

Might it be the fact that this is a DataSet from an SQL connection and that I can't write this to my mdb connection via my OleDbAdapter or am I just missing the obvious here?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After endlessly trying to use the DataAdapter.Update(Method) I gave up.. I settled for using an sdf file instead of an mdb.

If I need to update my database, I remove the local database, create a new one, using the same connectionstring. Then I loop over the tables in my dataset, read the column names and types from it and create tables based on that.

After this I loop over my dataset and insert the contents of my dataset which I filled with the information from the server. Below is the code, this is just 'quick and dirty' as a proof of concept but it works for my scenario.

```
public static void RemoveAndCreateLocalDb(string strLocalDbLocation)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(strLocalDbLocation))
            {
                File.Delete(strLocalDbLocation);
            }
            SqlCeEngine sceEngine = new SqlCeEngine(@"Data Source= " + strLocalDbLocation + ";Persist Security Info=True;Password=MyPass");
            sceEngine.CreateDatabase();
        }
        catch
        { }
    }

public static void UpdateLocalDatabase(String strTableName, DataTable dttTable)
    {
        try
        {

            // Opening the Connection
            sceConnection = CreateDatabaseSQLCEConnection();
            sceConnection.Open();

            // Creating tables in sdf file - checking headers and types and adding them to a query
            StringBuilder stbSqlGetHeaders = new StringBuilder();
            stbSqlGetHeaders.Append("create table " + strTableName + " (");
            int z = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn col in dttTable.Columns)
            {
                if (z != 0) stbSqlGetHeaders.Append(", "); ;
                String strName = col.ColumnName;
                String strType = col.DataType.ToString();
                if (strType.Equals("")) throw new ArgumentException("DataType Empty");
                if (strType.Equals("System.Int32")) strType = "int";
                if (strType.Equals("System.String")) strType = "nvarchar (100)";
                if (strType.Equals("System.Boolean")) strType = "nvarchar (15)";
                if (strType.Equals("System.DateTime")) strType = "datetime";
                if (strType.Equals("System.Byte[]")) strType = "nvarchar (100)";

                stbSqlGetHeaders.Append(strName + " " + strType);
                z++;
            }
            stbSqlGetHeaders.Append(" )");
            SqlCeCommand sceCreateTableCommand;
            string strCreateTableQuery = stbSqlGetHeaders.ToString();
            sceCreateTableCommand = new SqlCeCommand(strCreateTableQuery, sceConnection);

            sceCreateTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


            StringBuilder stbSqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder stbFields = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder stbParameters = new StringBuilder();

            stbSqlQuery.Append("insert into " + strTableName + " (");

            foreach (DataColumn col in dttTable.Columns)
            {
                stbFields.Append(col.ColumnName);
                stbParameters.Append("@" + col.ColumnName.ToLower());
                if (col.ColumnName != dttTable.Columns[dttTable.Columns.Count - 1].ColumnName)
                {
                    stbFields.Append(", ");
                    stbParameters.Append(", ");
                }
            }
            stbSqlQuery.Append(stbFields.ToString() + ") ");
            stbSqlQuery.Append("values (");
            stbSqlQuery.Append(stbParameters.ToString() + ") ");

            string strTotalRows = dttTable.Rows.Count.ToString();

            foreach (DataRow row in dttTable.Rows)
            {
                SqlCeCommand sceInsertCommand = new SqlCeCommand(stbSqlQuery.ToString(), sceConnection);
                foreach (DataColumn col in dttTable.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.ColumnName.ToLower() == "ssma_timestamp")
                    {
                        sceInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + col.ColumnName.ToLower(), "");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sceInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + col.ColumnName.ToLower(), row[col.ColumnName]);
                    }
                }
                sceInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: this is a wild stab in the dark, but could you open two connections, create 2 commands one that reads from your external database, one that writes to the internal one, and from there say updateLocalBackUpcmd.paramaters.addwithvalue("@Paramater", reader.readline(1)) 

I don't know if that's possible but could stop you having to use a local dataset? you might also be able to save time by using an UPDATE command instead of deleting and repopulating the database

Answer (score 1):

For a straight backup from the external database to the internal backup

I've just been messing around with an sdf and a server based sql database and it has worked.. It's not by all means the finished product but for one column I've got the program to read from the external database and then write straight away to the local .sdf in around 15 lines of code

```
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection( ExternalDatabaseConnectionString );
            SqlCeConnection sqlCECon = new SqlCeConnection( BackUpConnectionString );
            using ( sqlCon )
                {
                using ( sqlCECon )

                    {
                    sqlCon.Open( );
                    sqlCECon.Open( );
                    SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand( "Select * from [TableToRead]", sqlCon );
                    SqlCeCommand save = new SqlCeCommand( "Update [BackUpTable] set InfoColumn = @info where ID = @id", sqlCECon );
                    SqlDataReader reader = get.ExecuteReader( );
                    if ( reader.HasRows )
                        {
                        reader.Read( );
save.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", reader.GetString(0));
                            save.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@info", reader.GetString( 1 ));
                            save.ExecuteNonQuery( );
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

For one row of a database, backing up one column, it works, I'm assuming you will have some sort of auto incremented key like ID?

Comment: Hi Alex, wow this would be so cool if you 'cracked' it. I am using a database with 3 Tables and all of them have an auto incremented ID column in them.. If I implement this, I assume I can get this to work by looping over this for each of my tables? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a first step would be to reduce your reliance on `static` methods and fields.

If you look at your `UpdateLocalDatabase` method you'll see that you are passing in `strTableName` which is used by that method but a method that `UpdateLocalDatabase` calls (`CreateDatabaseConnection`) refers to a different global static variable named the same.  Most likely the two `strTableName` variables contain different values and you are not seeing that they are not the same variable.

Also you are trying to write out the global static data set `dtsTableContents` in `UpdateLocalDatabase` but if you then look at `CreateDatabaseConnection` it actually creates a local version of that variable -- again, you have two variables named the same thing where one is global and one is local.

I suspect that the two variables of `dtsTableContents` is the problem.

My suggestion, again, would be to not have any static methods or variables and, for what you're doing here, try not to use any global variables. Also, refactor and/or rename your methods to match more what they are actually doing.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for your answer. I'll try ad use somewhat less (global) static variables. The reason I use them is because these code snippets are in a separate DLL and are being triggered by a main executable. I can say for sure that it is not related to the dtsTableContents because it gets assigned before triggering this method but I left that part out as my question was already getting too long. what would be the best way without setting global static variables to interact quickly with my dlls and exes? The other option I assume would be to create a seperate instance everytime? - thanks

Comment: @Xikiryox, I would suggest stepping through the code in the debugger. Since this is a separate DLL and if it's in a different process, you may have to Debug | Attach Process to debug it. I'm not convinced that going all static is going to be that beneficial, especially since the code you've given looks likes there's a lot of room to have things go unexpectedly. I would start by changing this to non-static and not use as much global variables as possible because I believe this will illuminate some current issues. Once it works that way, then consider static if you need the performance.

Comment: as an idea : did you tried to check internet connection availability and then try connect to the server ? and why you didn't wirte your dataset completely to some XML documents on the PC and save it in app path?

Comment: @sihirbazzz The reason why is because the database is encrypted and not all data should be visible so that's why I can't drop the information in an XML File. So I am somewhat stuck because I have to use an sdf/mdb/accdb file - thanks.